# How can I guarantee the scheduling by ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor will not die abruptly?

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice, executor

I'm a newbie programmer who's grappling with this issue of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

Upon some googling I got to know how to handle the exceptions from Runnable() part by using afterExecute method. Now it boils to down to this.

What if the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor's scheduleAtFixedRate() method breaks out an error and the thread stops all of the sudden?

> In other words, what if the 
>    error is from the Executor class and not from the Runnable
>   implementation?

Is there any way that I can catch errors && deal with it (by restarting the whole scheduling) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> what if the error is from the Executor class and not from the Runnable
>   implementation?

The error does not come from the executor class.

> Is there any way that I can catch errors && deal with it (by
>   restarting the whole scheduling) ?

Yes you can use different techniques to recognize an error and restart `ScheduledExecutorService`, but the real question should be: is that the right thing to do ?

If you can deal with the error in your Runnable, better deal with it there instead of paying the toll of restarting an Executor.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
So are you saying that  errors come only from the Runnable implementations so that I don't need to bother?  
There seems to be cases of error from the class itself if you see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() , the singlethreadexecutor has something that resumes its work upon the scheduling's own failure, not from the runnable implementation?

Comment: There are 3 exceptions that can be raised by [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) and they all occur because of either incorrect usage or misbehavior of the Runnable.

Comment: @sanghyun a concrete example would be helpful here

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see your mentioned concrete example.

Comment: @sanghyun sorry for not being clear: I'm saying that if you'll provide a concrete example it will be easier to discuss. What's the task that you're sending to the executor, in what frequency it needs to run, how long does it take to execute, what are the reasons that the task will fail (raise an exception) and etc.

Comment: I think I'm through with the issue now. It's pity that I can't vote your answer up for I've just started stackoverflow! thanks!

Comment: @sanghyun don't worry about it, hope it help and welcome to SO!